# Selecting elements from array according to indices specified in another array c#

Tags: c#, arrays, linq, select, lambda

Suppose we have an array with data:

```
double[] x = new double[N] {x_1, ..., x_N};
```

And array of size `N` containing labels corresponding to the elements of `x`:

```
int[] ind = new int[N] {i_1, ..., i_N};
```

What is the fastest way to select all elements from `x` that have certain label `I` according to `ind`?

For example,

```
x = {3, 2, 6, 2, 5}
ind = {1, 2, 1, 1, 2}
I = ind[0] = 1
```

Result:

```
y = {3, 6, 2}
```

Clearly, it can be easily (but not efficiently and clean) done with loops, but I think there should be the way how to do that using `.Where` and lambdas..Thanks

EDIT:

The answer provided by MarcinJuraszek is completely correct, thanks. However, I've simplified the question in hope that it would work in my original situation. Could you please take a look what is the problem if we have generic types:

```
T1[] xn = new T1[N] {x_1, ..., x_N};
T2[] ind = new T2[N] {i_1, ..., i_N};
T2 I = ind[0]
```

Using the solution provided I get an error "Delegate 'System.Func' does not take 2 arguments":

```
T1[] y = xn.Where((x, idx) => ind[idx] == I).ToArray();
```

Thank you very much

Answer (score 18, accepted):

How about that:

```
var xs = new[] { 3, 2, 6, 2, 5 };
var ind = new[] { 1, 2, 1, 1, 2 };
var I = 1;

var results = xs.Where((x, idx) => ind[idx] == I).ToArray();
```

It uses second, less popular, `Where` overload:

[`Enumerable.Where<TSource>(IEnumerable<TSource>, Func<TSource, Int32, Boolean>)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549418.aspx)

which has item index available as predicate parameter (called `idx` in my solution).

***Generic version***

```
public static T1[] WhereCorresponding<T1, T2>(T1[] xs, T2[] ind) where T2 : IEquatable<T2>
{
    T2 I = ind[0];
    return xs.Where((x, idx) => ind[idx].Equals(I)).ToArray();
}
```

*Usage*

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var xs = new[] { 3, 2, 6, 2, 5 };
    var ind = new[] { 1, 2, 1, 1, 2 };

    var results = WhereCorresponding(xs, ind);
}
```

**Generic + `double` version**

```
public static T[] Test<T>(T[] xs, double[] ind)
{
    double I = ind[0];

    return xs.Where((x, idx) => ind[idx] == I).ToArray();
}
```

Comment: It is very nice, thanks. Could you please look at the edited version of question?

Comment: For generics you have to be sure `T2 == T2` (or `T2.Equals(T2)`) is defined - add generic constraint `where T2 : IEquatable`

Comment: Can you advice how should I incorporate this constraint?

Comment: Thank you. I'm sorry, but I'm getting an error. If `xs` is `T1` and `ind` is `T2` and `results` is `T2` it says that "The type T2 cannot be used as type parameter... no boxing conversion or type parameter conversion from T2 to System.IEquatable<T2>". I know that I;m doing something wrong, your answer is great. I would appreciate help if you can

Comment: Class you're using as `T2` does not implement `IEquatable<>`. Implement it and it's gonna work.

Comment: The variable of type `T2` would have `double` type always. Is there a way how to specify that the array is `double[]` when passing `ind` to `WhereCorresponding`?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27510/discussion-between-marcinjuraszek-and-user2028058)

Answer (score 5):

This is a classic use for [**Enumerable.Zip**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267698.aspx), which runs through two enumerables parallel to eachother. Using Zip you can get your results with one pass. The following is completely type-agnostic, though I use `int`s and `string`s for illustration:

```
int[] values = { 3, 2, 6, 2, 5 };
string[] labels = { "A", "B", "A", "A", "B" };
var searchLabel = "A";

var results = labels.Zip(values, (label, value) => new { label, value })
                    .Where(x => x.label == searchLabel)
                    .Select(x => x.value);
```